# Angular UI / Select2 sometimes not loading "model"

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

1. **The goal:** Get a Select2 control with wich I can add one or more industry to customers.
2. **What I have tried:** see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/tqSmiE?p=preview
3. **The problem:** Sometimes the data already associated with the customers. i.e. the industry_id's it has in it's `industries` property are not loaded/ used by select2. It might require several manual reloads to see it, but for me it happens every 2-5 reloads.
4. **Screenshot of expected behavior:** [image: Screenshot of expected behavior]
5. **Screenshot of faulty behavior:** [image: Screenshot of faulty behavior]
6. **Third possibility, also faulty:** [image: Third possibility, also faulty]

Comment: Can't repeat the problem in Chrome.

Comment: I'm using chrome as well. Have not tested it on other browsers or internet connections. It does take several tries to replicate sometimes though.

Comment: yeah, I tried several times. Can't repeat. Maybe something else break ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wjvXf1?p=preview)

Use watch to make sure industries is loaded ?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm, i'm going to read about `$watch` in de docs again!

Comment: I improved on this solution by saving the result of the call to `CustomersService` in a temp variable and in the `$watch` callback i write `$scope.customers` = `$scope.customersTemp`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that sometimes the industries json is loaded after the customers json. When the customers array is repeated the industry_id's don't exist yet in the industries array and are discarded by Select2.

I believe the solution thus lies in making sure the industries array is available before the customers array get's ng-repeated. **The question now is: how?**